# TikTokApi playwright._impl._api_types.Error

Tags: python, api, playwright, tiktok-api

im trying to do some stuff with TikTokApi, i installed both the api and playwright by using these commands :

```
pip install TikTokApi
python -m playwright install
```

and got the sample code to test it out from the documentaion :

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

# Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uCt1x8kINQ for a brief setup tutorial
with TikTokApi() as api:
    for trending_video in api.trending.videos(count=50):
        # Prints the author's username of the trending video.
        print(trending_video.author.username)
```

and i get this error that i couldn't find the solution for, if anyone knows whats going on please help me out here :

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'S[A][m(a[oprand[1]],oprand[1])]')
```